# Making a qqplot in R for functions

Tags: r, qq-plot

The question is: **given that I have a data set and a theoretical cumulative distribution defined as a function, how can I make a qqplot to compare them?**

I cooked up a solution as follows: I chose a domain for the empirical distribution and evaluated it over those points, obtaining an image. Then, I constructed inverses of this image under the theoretical distribution, using a kind of Newton-Raphson iteration. I only had to plot the result against the initial domain. This works practically. But I feel there has to be a better way.

**EDIT:** I reformulated my question and I wanted to signal that I have in the meantime found a more elegant way to apply my 'cooking method' in that I found that I could more efficiently compute the inverse by using the function uniroot of the stats library. This in effect does the iteration procedure for me, in a much more efficient way than I could program myself.

Nevertheless, I'm still looking for a more compact approach. Maybe a variant on qqplot that does all this directly. In a sense, what I'd like to have is this

> qqplot(data,distribution=function(x) {...} );

Comment: Just use the qqplot function

Comment: ppoints might help too

Comment: Since `KClayton` is not a CDF--not even when $t$ is limited to positive values, which are the only ones for which the calculation makes sense for general values of the parameter--it's difficult to determine what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: @whuber : don't fixate on the particular example. Just take the question as if it was for any cdf. (But just in case, $t \in [0,1]$ and the parameter $\theta$ is a positive real number. KClayton is a function related to the generator of the Clayton copula. The reason I want to study this function has to do with a fitting technique introduced in a paper by Genest and Rivest (1993), "Statistical Inference Procedures for Bivariate Archimedean Copulas " ).

Comment: @kjetil b halvorsen : And how do I exactly use it with one data set and a function ? I thought of generating a second data set by sampling from the function. But I don't like this approach. I have the actual distribution function, I should be able to work with it directly.

Comment: Did you read the help pages for qqplot? Type ?qqplot and look at the examples se tion, thatshould help (Im om my phone now socannot give an example myself)

Comment: @kjetil b halvorsen : I did and it didn't help. qqplot seems to only allow two plot the quantiles of two data sets against each other. It doesn't seem to allow for plotting data against quantiles derived from a function.

Comment: Say if you want the quantiles for the $t_{10}$ distribution, you use the corresponding quantile function qt, say qt(ppoints(100), df=10) if you have 100 observations. That should give the wanted theoretical quantiles (from memory, untested since I dont have R on my phone, sad but true)

Comment: Your examples and code loom large in importance because you don't otherwise provide much background to go on.  Perhaps, as you intimate, we should treat them as distractors.  Would it be fair, then, to ignore the entirety of your post except for the question itself, "how can I make a qqplot to compare a CDF to data?"

Comment: @whuber : Yes, you can ignore that all. Just assume the CDF is given by a user defined function, that is all. I'll rewrite my post to reflect that since the rest are indeed distractors.

Comment: @kjetil b halvorsen : That's how I solved it in the end. But, the distribution I have is user defined. So I had to compute the quantiles myself, which I solved by using uniroot to find the inverse of the cdf. Still, I wonder if there is a more direct approach. Maybe a package that contains a specific quantile-quantile plot procedure that is more versatile.

Comment: You could make a function yourself q_mydist taking the p_mydist (your cdf) as input and using uniroot internally. The beuty of R os that it is functional, so you can compose userdefined with predefined function. The beauty comes from that composability, and not from having big monster predefined functions. Thefunctionyouneed shouldnt be more than ten lines

Comment: You don't need to invert the CDF.  Why not just order the data values $x_1\le x_2 \le \ldots \le x_n$ and apply the CDF to each of them to produce quantiles $q_1 \le q_2 \le \ldots \le q_n$? Associate each of these ranked data with probability plotting points $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n$ (such as $(1-1/2)/n, (2-1/2)/n, \ldots, (n-1/2)/n$) and plot the ordered pairs $(p_i,q_i)$.  Done.